# How to trigger useEffect() hook at each setMyState() even if the new value equals the previous value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to implement a logic where I need to perform an action every time a component uses `setMyState(value)` (where I note the previous value of the state as `preValue`) using the `useEffect()` hook with `myState` as a dependency.

This works as I want when `value !== prevValue`. However, if `value === prevValue`, the hook doesn't trigger, which is logical in term of optimization. But what would be the correct way to still trigger the hook at each `setMyState(value)` call ? It may be a design flaw as I'm quite new to React.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Put the state variable in the dependency array of the useEffect?

Comment: it is already, but it doesn't change value so it does not trigger the hook

Comment: don't pass a dependency array and it will run on every render

Comment: `useEffect` with no dependency array might work. But that will only be called for each render. `useEffect(() => { /* Operation that you want to perform */ })`

Comment: yes but the problem is that there are other states that trigger other renders and that would trigger my action way too much

Comment: Then, implement that logic in the handler or actions that triggers the ```setMyState(value)```. for example inside ```clickHandler```.

Comment: Thank you @Medi , redesigning and forwarding the logic to the child component that has the clickHandler worked well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `useEffect` only trigger when new value is different than previous value.
But you can use this hack to trigger `useEffect` on every value change.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ name: "" });

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("called... " + state.name);
}, [state]);

const onValueChange = (e) => {
  setState({ name: e.target.value });
};

return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Car</h1>
    <select name="cars" id="cars" onClick={onValueChange}>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>);
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-effect-on-same-value-se9d9)

Comment: thank you it works ! so the fact that the state is a dict has this effect ... Can you explain why ? And do you think it is a bad practice or it is ok ?

Comment: @aurelien_morel it's because dict isn't a primitive data type like int,string etc